# Initialize member variable once in class

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I have the following two classes:

```
class foo{
public:
     foo(){
         Configuration config;
         config.a=5;
         config.b=5;
         //...
         config.z=5;
         eng=Engine(config);
     }
private:
     Engine eng;
}

class Engine{
public:
    Engine(){
         //Very have model loading from hard disk is occurs here
         //This loading is depend on the values of config
    };
    Engine(Configuration const& config):config(config){
         //Very have model loading from hard disk is occurs here
         //This loading is depend on the values of config
    }
private:
    Configuration config;
}
```

It is obvious the way of initializing the `eng` member variable in `foo` `constructor` is very bad becuase `eng` has been initialized twice (which is very expensive). In order to solve this problem I made the `eng` as `unique_ptr` and initialized once in the `foo constructor` using `std::make_unique`:

```
class foo{
    public:
         foo(){
             Configuration config;
             config.a=5;
             config.b=5;
             //...
             config.z=5;
             eng=std::make_unique<Engine>(config);
         }
    private:
         std::unique_ptr<Engine> eng;
    }
```

This solved the problem of unnecessary initializing. However, I think that I have solved it in the wrong way. I can not see an obvious reason to use `pointers`. I think that there is a better solution with `stack member variables`.

The question is : Is it true that pointer-based solution should be avoided as much as possible? If yes, what is the best solution for my case?

**EDIT:**

Someone may thought of simple solution that I should provide a `setter` method for the `config` in the `engine` class. So, I can just set it after loading. This is not an option because the loading process is depending on the `config`. So if I change the `config` I should **reload** again.

Comment: Perhaps `Engine(Configuration config):config(config){` should be `Engine(const Configuration& config):config(config){` for performance

Comment: Yes sure it is like that.. I just write this code for SO. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps posting the code that you actually use is a better bet for more informative answers

Comment: I will try to imitate it as possible but posting all the code is not an option due to its size and its copyright. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the preparation of `Configuration` to a member function:

```
class foo{
public:
     foo() : eng(prepare_config()){
     }

     Configuration prepare_config() {
         Configuration config;
         config.a=5;
         config.b=5;
         //...
         config.z=5;
         return config;
     }
private:
     Engine eng;
}
```

Make sure you do not access any `foo` members in `prepare_config()` (or just make `prepare_config()` static).

Comment: That kind of solution that I was looking for.. Many Thanks.. BTW, do you think that this solution is absolutely better than using pointers ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, I don't like to say that something is _absolutely_ better than anything else. Each solution has its advantages and disadvantages; it all depends on finer details of your situation. For example, this code might be more difficult and error-prone if you actually _need_ some `foo` members to prepare `Configuration`.